# Foreach: Get All The Keys That Have The Value "X"

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

Suppose I have an array like this:

```
$array = array("a","b","c","d","a","a");
```

and I want to get all the keys that have the value "a".

I know I can get them using a `while` loop:

```
while ($a = current($array)) {
    if ($a == 'a') {
        echo key($array).',';
    }
    next($array);
}
```

**How can I get them using a `foreach` loop instead?**

I've tried:

```
   foreach ($array as $a) {
        if ($a == 'a') {
            echo key($array).',';
        }

    }
```

and I got

> 1,1,1,

as the result.

Comment: @myro ??? `echo ($a).',';` I will get the value `a` and the result will be `a,a,a,`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you would like all of the keys for a particular value, I would suggest using [`array_keys`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), using the optional `search_value` parameter.

```
$input = array("Foo" => "X", "Bar" => "X", "Fizz" => "O");
$result = array_keys( $input, "X" );
```

Where `$result` becomes

```
Array ( 
  [0] => Foo 
  [1] => Bar 
)
```

If you wish to use a `foreach`, you can iterate through each key/value set, adding the key to a new array collection when its value matches your search:

```
$array = array("a","b","c","d","a","a");
$keys = array();

foreach ( $array as $key => $value )
  $value === "a" && array_push( $keys, $key );
```

Where `$keys` becomes

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 0 
  [1] => 4 
  [2] => 5 
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below to print out keys with specific value

```
foreach ($array as $key=>$val) {
        if ($val == 'a') {
            echo $key." ";
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
foreach($array as $key=>$val)
{
  //access the $key as key.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here's a simpler filter.

```
$query = "a";
$result = array_keys(array_filter($array,
    function($element)use($query){
        if($element==$query) return true;
    }
));
```